# Resize a modal dialog according to its content size dynamically

Tags: jquery, jsp, resize, popup, modal-dialog

I have a modalDialog opening from a jsp page which fetches data from db and shows it (on the modalDialog) as a simple table. Now, on calling the modal popup from the jsp, I am specifying its width and height, but I want that the end popup should have a height just sufficient to hold the table (i.e. the table height may differ if more rows may get fetched). I need to do this resizing only once on the comlplete load of the modalDialog popup. But I am not able to figure out any way. I have tried different options in $(document).ready handler, but of no avail.

Here's how I am calling the modalDialog in the parent jsp:

```
var varURL = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myController/actionStatus.htm?Transaction_id="+trans_id;
if (window.showModalDialog) {
    window.showModalDialog(varURL, "popupActionStatus", "dialogWidth:521px; dialogHeight:400px");
    closeAllPopups();
} else {
    window.open(varURL, 'popupActionStatus', 'height=400, width=600, toolbar=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, modal=yes');
    closeAllPopups();
    }
```

Now i need to resize this popup on its load according to the height of the table which it contains:

Script:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        jQuery('.popupStatusDetails').show();
        $("#actionStatusPopupTable").tablesorter({
        cancelSelection : true
        });
    });
```

And the body of the popup is something like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="popupStatusDetails" style="top: 0%;left: 0%" id="div1">
        <table id="actionStatusPopupTable" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" class="tableborder">
            <thead>
                <tr> Headers here </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr> Data rows here </tr>
                <tr> Data rows here </tr>
                <tr> Data rows here </tr>
                ...........
            </tbody>
        </table>
   </div>
</body>
```

I tried using this also on window.load, document.ready etc, but can't figure out any solution:

```
window.dialogHeight = document.getElementById("popupStatusDetails").style.height;
```

I guess these things don't work coz it's a modalDialog, but then there must be some way for sure :(

Comment: ... have you tried getting the height of the table as in $('actionStatusPopupTable').outerHeight() and setting the height of whatever you need from that?

Comment: Yes, it didn't work. No effect on the height with it. I set the popup's height with it, but it didn't get changed.

Comment: You may take a look at http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/. Maybe this helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
function showCenteredLayer(layerID) {
var object = $('#'+layerID);
object.css("position","absolute");
object.css("top", ( $(window).height() - object.height() ) / 2+$(window).scrollTop() + "px");
object.css("left", ( $(window).width() - object.width() ) / 2+$(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
MM_showHideLayers(layerID,'','show');
}
```

This is some JQuery code I use for centering soft-dialogs in a webpage.  Could you use this kind of code to calculate dimensions and then feed into window.open?

Hmm... perhaps load the object into a hidden DIV, and see if JQuery can guess the dimensions even if it's not shown?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if something like this might work for you - something similar is serving for me quite well...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  //Determine page size
  var $actionStatusPopupTable= $("#actionStatusPopupTable");
  var iWidth = $actionStatusPopupTable.width() + 20,
    iHeight = $actionStatusPopupTable.height() + 35;

  //Resize page to just larger than tblDetails
  if (document.all) {

    //IE
    window.dialogWidth = iWidth + "px";
    window.dialogHeight = iHeight + "px";
  } 
  else {

    //Non IE
    iHeight += 55; //Non IE quirk
    window.resizeTo(iWidth, iHeight);
  }
}
```